# Bridged network connection in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ftp, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:5.6-cli
VOLUME /usr/src/up
WORKDIR /usr/src/up
RUN docker-php-source extract \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql 
&& docker-php-source delete

RUN echo "date.timezone = Europe/Paris" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
```

This one create a new virtual machine with PHP 5.6, install pdo and pdo_mysql extensions and specify the timezone in php.ini.

The problem that I have is that by default, the virtual machine has a 'NAT network IP address'. Because of that, scripts with FTP connections don't work, I've got this error :

```
Warning: ftp_get(): I won't open a connection to 172.17.0.2 (only to x.x.x.x)
```

So I would like my virtual machine has a 'Bridged network IP address', and gets its IP address from my DHCP.

How can I do that ?
Could I include that into the Dockerfile in order to facilitate the work for other people ?

Thanks in advance !

Kind regards,
Thomas

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question; but did you consider using FTP in passive mode (using [`ftp_pasv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php))? In general, passive FTP should work better behind a NAT gateway.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not making the scripts unfortunately, and I can't modify them all the time :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default docker server creates a default bridge but [you can create your own bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/build-bridges/) and assign your container to that custom bridge on start. Or you can use `docker network` command which seems to be an easier path. That way you can specify the IP range to match with your DHCP settings.

## Create your own bridge

```
docker network create --driver=bridge \
--subnet=192.168.127.0/24 --gateway=192.168.127.1 \
--ip-range=192.168.127.128/25 yourbridge
```

Run the container using your custom bridge;

```
docker run -d --net=yourbridge ..
```

See this blog post for a concrete example:
http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-user-defined-networks/

> Within a user-defined bridge network, linking is not supported. You
>   can expose and publish container ports on containers in this network.
>   This is useful if you want to make a portion of the bridge network
>   available to an outside network.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! :-)
I tried to integrate the docker network command into the Dockerfile but apparently it is not the right way to do.
Do I have to do it separately from the Dockerfile ?
I would like to put the maximum into the Dockerfile in order to simplify the build for other futures users.

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards
Thomas

Comment: I don't think you can specify network in Dockerfile. But how are you running those docker containers now? You can create a bash script that creates a custom bridge and runs your container hooking it up to the bridge. This does not feel like a default scenario to me for other people though. Have you tried exposing ports with '-p' to external networks before going the long bridge way? Something does not feel right here.

Comment: Talking about this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what worked for you? For other people who end up here.

Comment: Sure. I just did your solution (create the bridge), and put it in a procedure for other people :)
Thanks for your help !